Can top-slicing be applied repeatedly in sequential years?
See my previous question about whether I've correctly understood top-slicing in general: Am I correct about how "top-slicing" works?
If my general understanding is wrong, then the premise of this question is invalid. If that's the case, please answer over on that question and I'll just close this one.

My impression is that the process for top-slicing doesn't actually check your incomes in previous years, and thus doesn't check for top-slicing relief granted in previous years.
I found references to "you can't top-slice multiple incomes within a single year" (or rather ... the calculation combines all top-slicing into one block before you start).
But AFAICT, you could top-slice in sequential years:

Earn, say, £10kpa less than the next tax band.
Have 2 long-term bonds/similar, set up so that they end up earning equivalent to £10kpa.
In one year claim the first bond, and use top-slicing so that the income exactly fills up your allowance up to the next band, implicitly spreading that income over the relevant previous years, and "filling each year up". With the net effect that you don't pay the higher rate on any of the 1st bond income.
In the next year claim the second bond and do the same top-slicing again, so that you still don't pay any higher band tax on the 2nd bond either.

In that imagining, you're implying that in the previous historic years you had:

your base income that fell £10k short of the tax band increase.
£10k from the 1st bond, that just filled you up to the limit of your current tax band, taxed at the lower rate.
??£10k from the 2nd bond, which also got taxed at the lower rate. ... even though it's conceptually over the limit for that historic year??

(happy to provide a more concrete example if that isn't clear)
Is that right?
Is this just loophole in the rules?
